# Range to Array - Insert formulas based on lookup value

Tags: arrays, excel, range

I am familiar with range to array subroutines. Rng = array; do something; array = Rng. I am trying to avoid a slow loop through several thousand records in a transactions database (Excel table) by putting the range into an array, then looking up a value in an adjacent column and depending on the value in that column, putting a formula into the range (array) cell. The formula varies depending on the value in the lookup column.  Here is some code how I am doing it now - slowly:

```
Dim ws as worksheet, rng as range, LastRow as long

Set ws = Sheets("Transactions")    
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("J2:J" & LastRow)   'basis

For Each cell In rngIf cell.Offset(0, 2) = "FT" Then                 'column L
    cell.Offset(0, 0) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Plan Hrs]]"
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Actual Hrs]]"

    ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 2) = "PT" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 0) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(PTMult,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Plan Hrs]]"
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(PTMult,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Actual Hrs]]"
    ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 2) = "Onsite" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 0) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(OnsiteM,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Plan Hrs]]"
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(OnsiteM,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Actual Hrs]]"
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 0) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Plan Hrs]]"
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Actual Hrs]]"
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

What I would like to do it something like:

```
dim arr as variant
    arr = rng
For c = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
If Cells(c, 12) = "FT" Then
arr(c, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Plan Hrs]]"

arr(c.Offset(0, 1)) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster[BASE],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],Roster[LASTNAME],0)),0)*INDEX(Multiplier,MATCH([@Project],Project,0))*[@[Actual Hrs]]"
....

rng = arr
```

Any suggestions are welcome. And BTW the table is an Excel table. The formulas work - I just need to insert the correct formula into the cells in column J (plan hrs) and k (actual hrs) based on the value in column L (FT, PT, or Onsite). Thanks.

Comment: When you are referencing a variant array (arr in your case), just use the row number and column number.  So instead of arr(c.Offset(0, 1)) = ...  just use arr(c, 1) = ......

Comment: Thanks. This got me closer - it runs very fast.  My range starts on row 2, and when I reference Cells(c,11) it puts the formula in arr(c,1) one row down. I am unsure how to correct. I changed the range to J1 from J2, but that doesn't work.  Tried to adjust to arr(c-1,1) but that doesn't work either.  Perhaps change the base from 0 to 1?

Comment: When you assign a range to an array, the dimensions of the array are exactly the same as the size of the range.  However the indexing of the array always starts at 1 for both rows and columns.  If you set rng = ws.Range("J2:J" & LastRow) and then assign arr = rng the array element arr(1,1) corresponds to Cell J2 on your sheet.  Without seeing all your code it is difficult to be sure but column J is the 10th column and you seem to be out by an offset of 10.

Comment: The columns are good, it's the rows that are off by one. I look up a value in column L - "FT", "PT", or "Onsite" and based on that value I assign each array element a formula that differs for each of the lookup values, and then copy the array back to the J range. but the range starts at J2 and as you say above the array(c,1) value starts at 1. So when I put the array back to the range the formulas are offset by 1 below where they should be.  I solved the issue by using "rng4.Offset(-1,0) = arr" when I copy the array back to the range but this is not an elegant solution - but it works.